# Link Button url count php and wordpress

Tags: loop, facebook, count

I have a function where it behind me facebook tanned number, the more accurate it brings me a number of shares that a post had! I tried to solve the function, more is giving an error and I need help!

Follows function:

```
function ia_fb_count($url_post) {
//Get the transient value from database
$fbcount = get_transient( 'fblcount' );
    if ( empty( $fbcount ) ){
        //If no value stored, get the like count
        $file = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/?ids='".$url_post."'");
            $jd = json_decode($file);
            $fbcount = number_format($jd->{'shared'});

        // Set the facebook likes transient value for 24 Hours
        set_transient('fblcount', $fbcount, 60*60*24 );
        // Also, return it at the same time
        return $fbcount;
    } else {
        // Transient Value is present, return it
        return $fbcount;
    }
}
```

call the function in my theme like this:

```
$url_post = the_permalink(); 
echo ia_fb_count($url_post);
```

Comment: What is the error it is giving you?...

Comment: @Howdy_McGee is not showing the number of shared is showing the link url.. look: http://www.tickimg.com.br/uploads/_url_faceboo.jpg

Comment: you can't assign `the_permalink()` to a variable, it echoes its value, use `get_permalink()`.